# Microsoft Excel, =TODAY() through a condition displays strange number instead of date

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am not sure if I am just over looking something, because I am still a very newbie to Excel's functions, so here comes the problem :

Lets say that I have A1 cell, and I want to display todays date in another cell whenever the A1 cell isn't empty.

So I came with this :

in another cell :
IF(A1<>"";TODAY();"")

Todays date is 16.8.2015, but when I run TODAY() through a condition like this, the output is : 42232

Why would I get this weird number ?

Maybe I did syntax wrong ? Not sure.. I also tried to make =TODAY() in new cell, that displayed the 16.8.2015, and then I wanted to show that cell through that condition, it threw the "42232" again.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the cell format is Date and not General or Number.

The `TODAY` function returns a serial number which is equivalent to the amount of days since 1/1/1900.  That is why you are seeing the number instead of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell with the number and on the Home tab you can change the format to Date (See Below).

[image]

Every date in Excel is represented by a number. For example, the number 1 represents 1/1/1900. Whereas 42232 represents 8/16/2015.